# Can't see any install on Google Play of my app?

Tags: google-play-services, android-developer-api

I cant see the number of installs of my app on Google Play even though I know some people has installed it?Its been almost two days and I cannot see the number but I still got a review.

Comment: Well, you should ask google, or wait a couple of day

Comment: Thats what I did, very unhelpful answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support issue with a third-party website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this process can take several days to be visible to you, haven't you read the Terms of Use?

Comment: Thank you, I quckly read certain part only.